# Relative Error is not normally distributed

Tags: cross-validation, error, measurement-error

I have this model in machine learning, and in the end, I calculate the Relative Error to find out how off the model is from predicting based on the real data. This is the histogram that I obtain from the model.

[image]

What to do when the Relative Error curve of a Model in the Machine Learning is not normally distributed? Does this mean that the model is not well trained?

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand, you have many bins (30) for very few data points (86). Even if your underlying data are normally distributed, a histogram with such a high bins/data ratio will look pretty bumpy, for instance:

[image: example histograms]

R code:

```
nn <- 86
n_bins <- 30

par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for ( ii in 1:6 ) {
    set.seed(ii) # for reproducibility
    hist(rnorm(nn),breaks=n_bins,xlab="",main="")
}
```

More reading at [Understanding an abnormal grade distribution](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18747/4140).

On the other hand, I assume your relative errors are $\frac{y-\hat{y}}{y}$. It may well be that they *cannot* be normally distributed at all - for instance, if you know that $y>0$ and you very sensibly truncate your predictions from below at 0. Then the relative error *cannot* be larger than 1. But any normal distribution has unbounded support. So your relative error *cannot* be normal.

Bottom line: your histogram does not give cause for concern.

(You may still find [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352) helpful - the MAPE is an absolute analogue of the relative error, and much in that thread is also applicable to the relative error.)